# How to write FluentAssertion for nested collections, order independent?

Tags: c#, .net, fluent-assertions

Using FluentAssertions 3.5.1, I'm trying to assert that a List of Integer arrays is equivalent to another list of integer arrays, without caring about item order. This is not working. In trying to break this problem down, I've  tried to assert that they are equal when they *do* have the same order and that's not working either:

```
var a = new List <Int32[]> { new Int32[] { 1, 2 } };
var b = new List <Int32[]> { new Int32[] { 1, 2 } };

a.Should().BeEquivalentTo(b);
```

This gives me the message:

> Expected collection {{1, 2}} to be equivalent to {{1, 2}}, but it misses {{1, 2}}.

Perhaps `BeEquivalentTo` is not the right assertion for comparing nested collections??

Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix it by using next code:

```
a.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(b);
```

or

```
a.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(b);
```

It will work, because `ShouldBeEquivalentTo` is deep equals comparison and `Should().BeEquivalentTo()` isn't.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to the library and I haven't found any docs yet explaining these kinds of things yet ;(

Comment: You can find the ordering documentation [here](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/wiki#ordering). By default, it will ignore the order, unless you use the `WithStrictOrdering` option.